# What does a positive or a negative TD-Error mean (in DQN)?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

When training a DQN, for example on board games, the sign of the TD-error varies. Sometimes, it's:

- always positive
- always negative
- varying during the training of the algorithm

For example, on the graph below, we see this third behavior:
[image]

Does this mean something? E.g can we give this an interpretation that relates to how the agent is behaving/learning? (for example interpretations about the "surprise" of the network since the td-error is the Bellman equation approximation error)

Comment: Seems like it could depend on the learning rate and the inital point. Initial point would determine your sign to start with, and with a small enough learning rate, it's possible you could make the TD-error have the same sign all along?